# Suppression of single white-space character in html and glyph width

Tags: html, css

I am analyzing an html page where everywhere a div's text includes a white-space that is not part of a sequence of white-space characters, i.e. a *single* white-space in between words, *not a sequence of white-spaces* - that white-space does not appear in the browser display of the page. The words of each div just show as one long word rather than being normally separated by a white-space as seen in the source.

I know there's css styles that control the suppression of consecutive multiple white-spaces, but couldn't find anything that may cause this behavior of excluding-from-display even a single white-space from being displayed. Any pointer in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Latest version of Chrome not some old browser.....

The computed styles shown for a sample div, including inherited styles, are:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5977559685707092px;
-webkit-transform: matrix(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0);
-webkit-transform-origin: 0px 29.0078125px;
border-collapse: separate;
bottom: 294.40631103515625px;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
font-family: ff1;
font-size: 40px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 29.0078125px;
left: 54.198307037353516px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 18.5px;
position: absolute;
text-shadow: none;
unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
visibility: visible;
white-space: pre;
width: 913.8046875px;
word-spacing: 0px;
```

Comment: What do dev tools show for the DIV style? And can u show an HTML sample where the issue would occur?

Comment: I am not sure I can post the html itself, so this is a question that may only get answered by a general idea or advice. Not the greatest, I know.

Comment: Yikes!  Just looking at that list gives me a headache!  We only need to know the styles that are set by the page!

Comment: @SuperScript I am not sure how to filter for that (?)

Comment: @matt : Just use Chrome developer tools, select the element, go to computed tab on the right-side panel and scroll to the bottom.  Copy that for us.  Or just give us a link so we can see for ourselves.

Comment: And if you could post at least idea of HTML - it would help. To see which exact whitespaces are used how text is laid out etc.

Comment: I posted the computed styles now without including the inherited styles... hope this overlaps what @SuperScript meant above. If there's any possible CSS setting that may cause this behavior that can also be an answer.

Comment: Well within the [CSS Text Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-4/#text-space-collapse) spec it discusses the `text-space-collapse` property and in the future you may be able to set the value of this to `discard` which would have the behavior you talk about but it's not implemented anywhere so I don't know what is doing this..

Comment: You have `word-spacing:0px` there, try overwriting it with `word-spacing: normal` (adding !important if needed)

Comment: Throwing the generated styles into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q7VU/) shows that the word spacing is fine. This sounds like a custom font issue since the styling looks fine, except the fiddle uses browser default font and not `ff1`.

Comment: Positive `word-spacing` values add to the already existing space, a value of `0` will add no extra space hence it will stay the same. A negative value the width of a white space character `word-spacing: -0.25em;` would appear to remove all white space.

Comment: Thanks!!! it was the custom font indeed.. changing the font and spaces show up normally (although multiple spaces are not collapsed into one). I can speculate the custom font has a white-space defined in it such that it occupies no width on screen. Thanks for all other comments as well - they sure create a more concise picture of this  aspect affected by so many moving parts!

Comment: I further picked inside the font file with FontForge and found that the space character (U+0020) has a width of just 1 compared to widths of hundreds for all other glyphs in that font file. Seems to account for everything...

Comment: Could you answer your own question? Then it won't show up in the list of unanswered ones any more.

Comment: I was figuring @setek would have the 'first right of refusal'...

Comment: @MrLister I think maybe since this is such a specific case question, it could probably be closed rather than answered? I just don't think that anybody will be in the same situation and find this helpful. If somebody has a contrasting opinion on it I certainly can post what I wrote as an answer ...

Comment: It may be a rare occurrence, but since it answered this particular question, there's a chance this very same issue may exist for other people.

Comment: Sure thing :) @matt feel free to answer your own question, you did confirm the issue, so it's better if you write it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Apart from many other factors that affect whether white-space inside various html elements is displayed or not (if I have time I'll make a summary of them here in a subsequent edit), one thing that may *suppress* a white-space included in html from being displayed, is the glyph of the white-space character in the font applied to the html. If that glyph is such that the white-space character occupies no space at all, or an infinitesimal width, then white-space included in the html will be effectively absent in the display.

That may be the case in some custom fonts, and is helpful to know in those cases.

I dearly thank everyone who have contributed to the knowledge contributed for this question, which was all very relevant and encompassing on the topic.